# An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I've implemented a Tf2 Keras Layer but when I'm training I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: ada_cos_layer_1/truediv:0
```

I've seen some similar posts but their issue was with the `Lambda` layer, which I'm not using. I believe that, in my case, it has to do with an assignment to an attribute which is not a `tf.Variable` (`self.s`). However, I've already tried setting it as such or using `add_weight` without any help. My layer is the following:

```py
class AdaCos(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_classes, margin=None, logit_scale=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.s = math.sqrt(2)*math.log(n_classes-1)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super().build(input_shape[0])
        self.w = self.add_weight(name='weights',
                                shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.n_classes),
                                initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                trainable=True)
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_median(v):
        v = tf.reshape(v, [-1])
        mid = v.get_shape()[0]//2 + 1
        return tf.nn.top_k(v, mid).values[-1]

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, y = inputs
        # normalize feature
        x = tf.nn.l2_normalize(x, axis=1, name='normed_embd')
        # normalize weights
        w = tf.nn.l2_normalize(self.w, axis=0, name='normed_weights')
        # dot product
        logits = tf.matmul(x, w, name='cos_t')
        # add margin
        # clip logits to prevent zero division when backward
        theta = tf.acos(tf.clip_by_value(logits, -1.0 + 1e-5, 1.0 - 1e-5))

        B_avg = tf.where(tf.expand_dims(y, 1) < 1, tf.exp(self.s*logits), tf.zeros_like(logits))
        B_avg = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(B_avg, axis=1), name='B_avg')

        theta_class = tf.gather_nd(theta, tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(y, tf.int32), 1), 1, name='theta_class')
        theta_med = self.get_median(theta_class)
        
        with tf.control_dependencies([theta_med, B_avg]):
            self.s = tf.math.log(B_avg) / tf.cos(tf.minimum(math.pi/4, theta_med))
            out = tf.multiply(logits, self.s, 'arcface_logist')
        return out

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (None, self.n_classes)
```

Comment: `The graph tensor has name: arc_face_layer_1/truediv:0` it seems it belongs to another layer in your model and you should look for it there.

Comment: Sorry, it's because when I ran and got the error the layer had another name. I'll change that

Comment: I commented the line `self.s = tf.math.log(B_avg) ...` and I didn't get any errors. So it seems the attribution is really the issue

Comment: Then try `self.s = tf.Variable(math.sqrt(2)*math.log(n_classes-1))` and  `self.s.assign(tf.math.log(B_avg) / tf.cos(tf.minimum(math.pi/4, theta_med)))`